# Input range with two different values

Tags: html, input, ionic-framework, range, minimum

I was wondering if it already exists a way to have an input of type "range" with two different setteable values. The input I would like to achieve is something like [this](http://s14.postimg.org/psrwajrkh/range_input.png). The idea would be to set a range for a price. Meaning I would need to retrieve the "minimum" and the "maximum" from that input. Obviously, for the sake of learning, we can disregard the CSS style.

Is there a way to accomplish this with HTML5 or JavaScript? I've heard that there are some jQuery plugins that accomplish this, but I was wondering if there's a more "native" way of doing it. As an addition, I'm working with the mobile-oriented framework Ionic. If anybody knows about a plugin for Ionic that can achieve this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/). It includes all Javascript, CSS and HTML necessary.

Having a div like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

And using this:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [20, 80],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});
```

You can see an easy example of it working.